# React Native (expo) + Django JWT axios error

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, expo, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Trying to make Login Screen. Using axios to get data from Django JWT url('http://127.0.0.1:8000').
Tried to find url works from Postman and also from terminal and both worked, but I got AxiosError from simulator. Does anyone know why my base url not work on React Native App?
I tried 'http://localhost:3000/' and 'http://10.0.2.2:8000'too but not worked.

This is my Codes...

LoginScreen.js

```
const LogInScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/", body, config, console.log(body))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("token");
        AsyncStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access);
        AsyncStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh);
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
          "JWT " + AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
        navigate("Home");
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  };
```

console.log(body) showed up {"email":"test@mail.com","password":"Test1234"}
console.log('token') not showed up, and 'error' part pop up.

Django urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/user/', include('api_user.urls')),
    path('api/flashcard/', include('api_card.urls')),
]
```

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    # 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',

    'api_card.apps.ApiCardConfig',
    'api_user.apps.ApiUserConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000', "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )

}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=90),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', 'JWT'),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api_user.User'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

terminal worked find so i think the problem is React Native expo app part ...

```
$ curl -d '{"email":"test@mail.com" , "password": "Test1234"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/"
{"refresh":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9....","access":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...."
```

Comment: Alert pop up that 'A server/network error occurred. Looks like CORS might be the problem.' So maybe backend Django settings.py 's CORS part?

Comment: Try to use your actual ip address and see if it works.

Comment: yes... but still cannot connect with backend server...tried many variety ways like use redux, react, and fetch, axios, but get same error. could went through with React.js web app, but  not react native ... this is my first react native app project so I have no idea how to fix it... network says responseURL undefined. but dataSent got email password data.

Comment: try deploy your backend online (for example Heroku)

Comment: thank you for the advice. but I would like to use django backend... maybe CORS is problem. I read there is no concept of CORS in native apps, so I'd like to know how to use connect django backend to react native app.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help my error. I got an answer!! it was a simple mistake. Django part, I run server normally. But Mac user should add IP address from react native after runserver. So, python manage.py runserver 196.168.3.10:8000. this is from React native "Metro waiting on exp://192.168.3.10:19000" after QR code. I added 19000 before not 8000 so got error.